# ESIs with Varnish 2.1.5 for Anonymous Users

Tags: 7, proxies

We're trying to configure our sites running D7 to use ESIs with Varnish 2.1.5, and having a hard time figuring this out.

We have a file `/test.php` that is being included in the template via esi so it appears on *all* pages of our site. The call to the file is through (in the template)

```
<esi:include src="/test.php" />
```

Relevant vcl conf is:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
...
  // enable esi
  esi;
  // if url is test.php, set ttl to 15 s
  if (req.url == "/test.php") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 15s;
  }
}
```

The text from `test.php` appears when users are logged in, but does not appear when they are logged out -- which is what we're after. This is without the ESI module as that is for authenticated users.

Comment: "This is without the ESI module as that is for authenticated users." The ESI module works with anonymous and authenticated users; just be aware that all anonymous users are treated the same.

Comment: @mikeytown2 My understanding is that with the ESI module one can cache pages when users are authenticated, and also display fragments of dynamic content. Is my understanding amiss?

Comment: ESI in its current form is there to display fragments of dynamic content. It really doesn't care if your logged in or not as it treats user 0 (anonymous) as one user. So if all anonymous users are going to get the same experience you shouldn't have any issues with ESI.

Comment: @mikeytown2: Thanks for the clarification, the 1st line on project page: "ESI - or Edge Side Includes - is a **high performance caching** solution for **Authenticated users**" thew me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off Anonymous caching and see what results you get (caching should be handled by Varnish).

1. Go to admin/config/development/performance
2. Uncheck *Cache pages for anonymous users*

Comment: Does anonymous caching on that page imply caching at the Drupal level?

Comment: Yes, it caches at the Drupal level

Comment: Thanks this works! To better my understanding: A combination of "flush all caches" and varnish restart should clear all anonymous caches, right? I tried this, but the esi content was only visible when users were logged in. Why would that be?

Comment: I'm not real savvy on ESI, but I would check if Varnish is actually processing pages that are cached by Drupal, or if it's Apache that's processing it.  In other words, maybe Apache is handling the request instead of Varnish, and Apache cannot handle the <esi>.  Lots of assumptions in this comment!  Just throwing out some ideas.

Comment: For clearing the Varnish cache you should consider using https://drupal.org/project/purge and https://drupal.org/project/flush_page_cache which helps you flush the drupal cache/ varnish cache for a particular page when used along with purge.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working instance with Drupal7, Varnish and ESI in working state[Th ESI tags are getting replaced for both Anonymous and logged in users].

I can confirm that ESI tags work well with Drupal Page Cache. I don't see a reason you need to disable the Drupal Page cache for ESI tags to work.

And regarding the behavior that you were experiencing, I think the anonymous page cache was built you added your ESI tag and hence it was not displaying. I think clearing Drupal Cache and Varnish Cache could have just fixed your issue.

Comment: You can also check out my blog http://foobar.azrisolutions.com/drupal/drupal7-varnish-and-esi-the-holy-grail-of-caching-for-the-authenticated-users/ IF you want to know how to use the ESI module.